# Javascript in Dynamic PDF

Tags: javascript, excel, pdf

Javascript Question - I am working with dynamic pdf which is a mix of user defined values & math equations. It is comprised of lots of cells with dynamic user entered fields with math in the background. I know only the most basic javascript and hope someone can quickly tell me how would I say in javascript If "Cell B" has a value use that value in cell C's equation, however if "Cell B" is empty or zero use "Cell A"'s value in the equation in cell c. 
Cell A populates with the result of a mathematical equation of multiple cells above . 
Cell B is a user enter number
cell C is the value of adding 3 cells together

Answer (score 0):

Your questions is a bit confusing, but I hope this helps grant you an overview of what you are trying to accomplish in JavaScript.

```
var cellB = 1231; //User enter number
var cells = [1,2,3,4]; //Multiple cells numbers
var cellA = mathEquation(1,4,5,6);
var cellC = sumCells(); //cell81 and cell24 should be define variables

function mathEquation() {
    var result = 0;
    if(arguments.length != 0) {
        for (var i = 0, j = arguments.length; i < j; i++){
            //Do math equation for cells passed through the arguments
        }
    }
    return result;
}

function sumCells() {
    var sum = 0;
    if(arguments.length != 0) {
        for (var i = 0, j = arguments.length; i < j; i++){
            //Sum cell numbers passed through the functions arguments
            sum += arguments[i];
        }
    }
    return sum;
}

function someFunction(cellValue) {
  //Do stuff 
    console.log("do stuff");
}

if (typeof cellB != 'undefined' && cellB != 0) {
    someFunction(cellB);
} else {
    someFunction(cellA);
}
```